# Gradle: Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What does this error message mean? I don't have duplicated packages in my project

> Error:Execution failed for task ':SimpleReader:processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' 
>   You can temporarily disable this error with
>   android.enforceUniquePackageName=false However, this is temporary and
>   will be enforced in 1.0

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17

    }
    compileSdkVersion 17
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:sherlocknavigationdrawer')
    compile project(':libraries:googleplayservices')
    compile project(':libraries:androidslidinguppanel')
    compile files('libs/protocol-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/sentry-0.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.3.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In my case, the problem was because I was including:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

both the wearable play services, and the regular. 
I commented out the wearable part, and it works. 
Not sure if I'll need it, but it was included by default by the project wizard

Comment: Hmm, if I comment out google-maps lib, the compiler says that LocationClient cannot be found. strange... I think it's caused by the modular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks - this saved some time!

Answer (score 16):

today I met the same problem. I need to use Google Analytics, so I import google analytics lib following the tutorial:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
```

then compile the project, gradle tell me  `Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'`

I can definitely sure that I only directly import `com.google.android.gms` one time by `google analytics` lib.

so I navigate to `Project` tab in Android Studio to see what are the libs this project depend on, then I found `play-services-6.5.87` display in `External Libraries`, like following screenshot:

[image: see External Libraries]

so now I know there is another lib depend on `play-services-6.5.87`, but I don't which lib it is.

then I use a gradle command in console to see the project dependencies:

```
$ ./gradlew -q app:dependencies
```

[image: gradle dependencies]

the result tells me that `com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.6.0` depend on it.

so how we fix this problem, two way:

1. if you don't need this `audience-network-sdk`, just remove it. my project in fact doesn't need it.
2. if you also need `audience-network-sdk` and `google-analytics`, use `exclude group` grammar, like following snippet code.

   ```
   //facebook SDK
   compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.6.0') 
           {exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'}

   // google analytics
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
   ```

in your case, the `audience-network-sdk` can be any other lib that depends on same lib with other libs. here is just a thinking of how to resolve similar problems.

Comment: Perfect solution. Allowed me to identify where the duplicate dependency came from.

Comment: You can also use `exclude module: 'play-services'` instead of the `exclude group` command.

Comment: For easy find/search use the below command in windows
`gradlew -q app:dependencies > c:\dependencies.log`

Answer (score 7):

Try removing `compile project(':libraries:googleplayservices')` or `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'`. I am pretty sure they are the same library.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer, but don't helped(

Comment: I found solution! I'm only change gms play-service compile from  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23' in my build.gradle
After your post i'm understand that problem is in build.gradle file. Thank very much! +1

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, i got it resolved by following steps:

1. ionic platform rm android
2. ionic platform add android
3. ionic build android

Comment: completely irrelevant

Comment: You resolved me the identic issue buit with native Script.

Answer (score 1):

this is a problem with versions. if you have multiple dependencies of same package path ensure the versions are the same

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had confused with this problem for a long time.My issue is little different with the question though same error log. I want my sublib's buildtype same with my application's buildtype. So I assigned the buildtype for sublib as the document tells me.
[Gradle Plugin User Guide][1]

This the error I got.

processing flavorCustomResource

Error: more than one library with com.xxx.libCommon

This is my *structure*. lib1 and lib2 are independent of each other.

app

-> lib1 -> libCommon

-> lib2 -> libCommon

I got the error only when I build my custom buildtype.However, The release version was Ok.

**More details.** some parts of my build.gradle

app:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release{}
        custom{}
    }
}
configurations {
    flavorReleaseCompile
    flavorCustomCompile
}
dependencies{
    compile project(':lib1')
    flavorReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: ':release')
    flavorCustomCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: ':custom')
}
```

lib1:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
    buildTypes {
        release{}
        custom{}
    }
}

dependencies{
    releaseCompile project(path: ':libCommon', configuration: ':release')
    customCompile project(path: ':libCommon', configuration: ':custom')
}
```

lib2

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libCommon')
}
```

**Solution:** configure the lib2 as lib1. the problem will be solved.

lib2:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
    buildTypes {
        release{}
        custom{}
    }
}

dependencies{
    releaseCompile project(path: ':libCommon', configuration: ':release')
    customCompile project(path: ':libCommon', configuration: ':custom')
}
```

***Reason***

The problem is something about **Library Publication**

**The default publish is release. if lib2 is not configured, it will use the default publish libCommon(release version) which is different from lib1 -> libCommon(custom version) assigned by lib1's build.gradle.This comes the error.**

I wish my post will help someone struggle with the same issue or give some hint to him/her.

Comment: Good explanation. It helped me find my similar problem. For one of my internal library dependencies, I was depending on the release version from my custom build type.