# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: gradle, android-studio, wear-os

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2, and created a project with Android 4.1 and Android Wear 4.4.  I need to integrate it with Google Play Services.

I'm trying to follow the Google Play Services setup page for Android Studio here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

In Step 2, it says to add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

However, upon Sync, I get this message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
  You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
  However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

Here is my complete build.gradle file inside the mobile module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.OptimizedPrime.locationweartabs"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
}
```

It appears that the recommended dependency is conflicting with the wearable compile statement.  I do want to retain wearable support, and at the same time need Google Play Services.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that one of the libraries depends on the other one? Maybe there is a transitive dependency, so you don't need to add it.

Comment: This answer helped greatly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37772331/2371425. You need to make sure multiple `com.google.android.gms`s aren't being imported.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'
```

then you don't need:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

Delete the non-wearable one.

Comment: This worked.  The error went away and I can still use Location api.  Thank you!

Comment: In my case, `import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient` needs `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'`. So I delete the wearable one.

Answer (score 6):

May be possibly your are using have different types of dependencies with different versions:

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-**neededDependency**:***version***

Ex: If you are using both dependencies as mention below:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
> ```

Try to use same version for different dependencies Like:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
> ```

Thank you, hope helpful to you.

Comment: this actually helped. Had the problem with `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and