# Ionic (cordova) : Gradle: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build.gradle

I encountered an error when I execute Ionic run android,here is the error

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>   You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=fal
>   se
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0`

**Here are the plugins that I have added**

```
com.google.playservices 21.0.1 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.11.0 "Facebook Connect"com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation 0.5.11 "BackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 2.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer 0.8.3dev "EmailComposer"
de.neofonie.cordova.plugin.nativeaudio 3.1.0 "Cordova Native Audio"
nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus 1.1.2 "Google+"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.19 "SocialSharing"
nl.x-services.plugins.toast 2.1.1 "Toast"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 1.9.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

**and here my build.gradle dependencies**

// GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT! 
...

```
dependencies{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: ":CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
debugCompile project(path: ":com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:oauth634839-FacebookLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: ":com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:oauth634839-FacebookLib", configuration: "release")
debugCompile project(path: ":com.google.playservices:oauth634839-google-play-services_lib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: ":com.google.playservices:oauth634839-google-play-services_lib", configuration: "release")
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0" 
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0" 
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

...

**I know that the error comes from here, but I don't know how to let a single package com.google.android.gms, when I know I have not directly edit the file build.gradle**

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795074/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms)

Comment: that not the same problem, i'm working on ionic framework and i can't  directly edit the file build.gradle, as montioned // GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!

Comment: You may also look at this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775891/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-using-co/34776219#34776219

Answer (score 1):

if someone has the same problem here is the solution, https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-cordova-variants#section-clean-build
the problem came from the module "one signal"