# facing error on runtime more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

Android studio 2.2.2

Say default Dependency = `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

I am facing this error on runtime:

`Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'`.

when I was trying to replace the default play services dependency with the specific dependencies I need in my project to reduce the execution time.

Here is my app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blucursor.gpstrack"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.0"
        resConfigs "en", "fr"

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
             storeFile file("C:\\******\\********.jks")
             storePassword "********"
             keyAlias "*******"
             keyPassword "******"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.moxun:tagcloudlib:1.1.3'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the project level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This works fine when I build with the default one i.e:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`

What I tried:
Sources Which I followed.

- [Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795074/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms)
- [Gradle: Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494872/gradle-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37772331/5535870) solution got me quite close to what I wanted I tried deleting already generated folder(Lame thing to do) and clean, Gradle sync, invalidate Cache restart but no success.

I've seen many solutions which say you either have to use the play service dependency or the specific dependency.
I am trying to do the same but it doesn't seem working for me.
any help with this?

**EDIT**: Even when I remove all play store dependencies the same error persist.

I also tried updating the app.iml file and removed other playstore dependencies which are of no need for the project but this is still not working.

Comment: Have you tried making Firebase use the same version as the play services?

Comment: yes I tried doing that too but didn't worked out.

Comment: Well, as those questions you linked to point out, you should be able to inspect your Gradle dependency tree using the command line

Comment: well, I am not quite proficient working with the command line and gradle. but as you can see the third link in my question I found the Gradle dependency  tree which includes all the dependency from the default gradle even when I use specific dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked if you have more than one library in your `settings.gradle` and in your `build.gradle`?. So go to your build.gradle and delete it appears duplicated library.

Comment: my settings.gradle just have this line `include ':app'` and the other two I've attached the code in the question.

Comment: Try to use the same version for google play services and firebase. compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'

Comment: I tried doing this but didn't worked actually I tried to run this project on some different machine too (was thinking about some premission related thing) but didn't worked on other machines too,

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but i do this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' //use this version as the newest version
    }
```

and i did this too

```
 dependencies {
.
.
.
    //    compile project(':google-play-services') comment because this version isn't same with my firebase version, try to get the last google-play-service jar / compile the last version
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'com.google.android.gms'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // i do it on every project i have
```

then, sync your project and clean your project
may this help you, i think the version of google-play-service should be same as the firebase version

update

try to make your gms version same with your firebase version (if you use 9.8.0 in gms, use 9.8.0 in firebase)

Answer (score -2):

from project level gradle file remove this line classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'.

because you are already using in your app level gradle file.

Comment: I think it's necessary to use this line as this is essential for making use of "plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in app level gradle.

Comment: have you tried by removing that line and plugin line from app gradle file.

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'

Comment: this answer will resolve your problem     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494872/gradle-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms

Comment: that I tried you can see in the third link which i mentioned in the question this is the same.

Comment: It is completely wrong. Check the https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin. You have to add the classpath dependency to use the google play service plugin