# Android Error :react-native-google-signin:processReleaseResources

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

Suddenly, can't build my React Native Apps on Android. **I have never changed Android side but this error occurs while building.**

react-native: "^0.52.0",

react-native-google-signin: "git+https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-signin.git#v0.12.1",

```
:react-native-google-signin:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-google-signin:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-google-signin:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-signin:processReleaseResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494872/gradle-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms)

Comment: I checked this article already but I can't find a wearable library or other solution.

Answer (score 5):

I same problem too, i fix with this.
edit `\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
```

change `+` to `11.6.0`

Related with: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18479

Comment: Perfect! That would work, thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issues by adding in `android\build.gradle` the following

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                ...
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend against modifying `\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\build.gradle` as it would break on a clean `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

**if you are facing this issue while running ./gradlew assembleRelease command.**

You can fix this issue by replacing ./gradlew assembleRelease with ./gradlew app:assembleRelease

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by replace `./gradlew assembleRelease` by `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`