# AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I try to run My project in Android 14 ,I noticed one error like

AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:
aapt2.exe W 05-04 15:56:18  7008  7396 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.

```
android {

     compileSdkVersion = "android-UpsideDownCake"
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pro.sample"
        minSdkVersion 23

        targetSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
        versionCode 84
        versionName "5.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
        }
        ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
    }
}
```

This is my App level gradle file, how can I this ?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when compiling the app to target sdk version 34

- Upgrade AGP dependency from 7.0.4 to 7.4.2
- Upgrade Gradle version to 7.5
- Upgrade Gradle plugins

and the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, I too upgraded to API 34 and faced lot of issues. and your suggestion resolved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is what happened: I created a new Activity and then removed the Activity Class. When I tried to start the app again, I encountered the same error message. While checking the project, I noticed that the Activity.xml of the deleted class already existed. After deleting these XML files, I successfully resolved the error.

```
AAPT2 process unexpectedly exited. Error output: aapt2.exe W 03-02 14:38:07 10984 14684 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and found [a solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399387/android-error-react-native-google-signinprocessreleaseresources). You need to perform the following to modify the `build.gradle` file in `node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/android`:

- Look for and comment out the line that contains the `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth`.
- Add a new line `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+"`.
- Save your build.gradle file.
- In IntelliJ for Android, go to **File > Invalidate Caches..** and select **Invalidate and Restart**. This action will clear the cache and restart IntelliJ for Android.

This fixed version of **play-services-auth** with a configuration that dynamically selects the latest version available. Note that this is a temporary solution. You will need to reapply these adjustments every time you update or reinstall this library.